# Using IEnumerable.Repeat to populate a counter

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I want to create an IEnumerable list using Enumerable.Repeat and would like the set the Id of the objects to the *nth* element of the list as per the code below. Is this possible with  Enumerable.Repeat or would I need to do something different?

```
var stuff = Enumerable.Repeat("This is element <n>", 50);
```

So the resulting output from the following code ...

```
foreach (var s in stuff)
{
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

...would be ...

```
This is element 0
This is element 2
This is element 3
...
This is element 49
```

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually I use `Enumerable.Range` for such tasks:

```cs
var stuff = Enumerable.Range(0, 50)
    .Select(i => new thing {id = i})
```

It is not possible to achieve this task with `Repeat` cause it does exactly what it "promises" - repeats exactly the same element multiple times:

```cs
class thing{public int id;}
var counter = 0;
var stuff = Enumerable.Repeat(new thing { id = 1 }, 50)
    .ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(stuff[0], stuff[1])); // prints "True"
```